# Looking for Xmldb Oracle library

Tags: oracle

Where can I download the jar library Oracle xmldb:11.2.0.3 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the initial release from the oracle.com site, or the edelivery.oracle.com. Under the database download you would see a separate option for the client. This should contain the jar file you are looking for.

If it is specifically the 11.2.0.3 version you are needing, you will have to have an Oracle account WITH support account, login to the support site(s) (Flash: [support.oracle.com](http://support.oracle.com) , HTML: [supporthtml.oracle.com](http://supporthtml.oracle.com)). After doing so, you will use the patch search tool. Of the patchset listed files for 11g patchsets, the client is 3 of 6. For example, the Windows 32bit 11.2.0.3 patchset id is 10404530.